# how do i change flask-admin's locale?

Tags: flask-admin

I wanner change the locale, like:

> locale='zh_CN'

not admin's application's locale, I need change flask-admin's locale code.

Answer (score 0):

Try add parameter

```
?lang=zh_CN
```

to the end of the url request.

If that work, you may add

```
set $args $args&lang=zh_CN;
```

to your nginx conf file.